# Problem with Quick time playing on IE8

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, c#-4.0, azure, quicktime

I am trying to play the Video file on IE8 using quick time but i am getting some kind of wierd message on the window

**`RñQªÿ1ŠS×Wü5Å'*žã|Š—RÜ_qKq·âxæËŽ ÅK«ëË(þ¢â!ŠWP¼¢âaŠ«üâxI[Eq•w*ï8TÞq¨¼ãPyÇ¡òŽCå‡Ê;•w*ï8"T\å‡Ê;•w*ï8TÞq¨¼ãPyÇ¡òŽCåGŒâ=”|z*ÞK]ß[ñ~Š÷WRq•_c§økŠOT|²âSŸ¦øtÅg)>[ñ¹ŠÏS|¡â‹ÏU|‰âË_¡øJÅW)¾FñµŠoP|£â›ß¢øvÅw(¾KñÝŠïS|¿â‡?¬øQÅßQü]ÅßSü„â*~Jñ?­øgŠÿKñ/?§øWŠ_TükÅ/+þ­âß)þ½â×¿¡ø-Åo+~WñŸ ø/Š?TüwÅÿ|Îƒ?¢ýû€|xRè ø6*£¨æ³¥«Q©Oë/Kû†Ò´»tÓq1ÿã´MøÍÅš ¸Þ s­èÜÔÊÒï&ô›bŽûuj´>Ù¼‹ôíj%-„ù·«5Š¡.²qõë¢ë­¿é›|ÊEspQÞp‘¹Þ¢ ÇC]ÙÔ"¨Qìp- V“ÅDW}é“äÚ¡Ò×2÷ñ6ÍüÍE¹ÅEëueÊ1ÅCå!å7ë™×$éw™ŒAr°HŽ®vÔÈ¶]”o¬/d®keî<>ÅíÏ\¨•2}Y7d>uÍœ¬·¤o“äeQ>wõ—yð\ãåw3Ž½fžÇ¹†e×•Zi<&ëƒlÜõ5ÚZ$‹|ÊMöje‹ù>ÒS ÅLWOé7^æV_Æk%ý ãY3Ëšr¸ÕDô@yÃ]^äTCÖFcX$ 7ÝcÑyWª¹¯ÎN’;Í»Ì§ôûcY‹‡ÈçKù×Iº°† ÿ‰Za#7ër¸±5×"™ã*ùÍk¢xè¤Ømí6}»Y`**

if i copy the url and play in a new Tab i am able to play the video. any suggestion appreciated.

Fiddler Data

```
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Cache-Control: private Content-Length: 12172289
> Content-Type: video/quicktime Last-Modified: Mon, 15 Aug 2011 18:07:10
> GMT Accept-Ranges: bytes ETag: 0x8CE298D49679541 Server:
> Microsoft-IIS/7.0 x-ms-request-id:
> 9aa58ee1-e74e-4a42-ac76-2a90e4d05d33 x-ms-meta-Source:
> thepoint.contentconfiguration x-ms-meta-CreatedOn: 8/15/2011 6:06:21
> PM x-ms-meta-UpdatedOn: 4/28/2010 8:38:04 PM x-ms-meta-FileSize:
> 12172289 Server: Blob Service Version 1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
> X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Date: Wed, 07 Sep
> 2011 13:15:24 GMT
```

Comment: You tagged this as C#, ASP.net, and Azure ... can you provide some more details about what you are doing?

Comment: We have a blob storage, where our files will be saved and the user will be accessing the files through a website. the code is written in c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you specified the MIME type mappings for quicktime in the IIS config (web.config)?  Depending on the extension of your file and/or the URL, IIS would need to understand how to serve up the MIME type properly.

Something like

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".m4v" mimeType="video/m4v" />
     </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

may be required.

Using a web debug such as [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) would also enable you to see the Content-type header coming back.  That may provide you some clue as to what the server things its serving.

For example, if it believes that this url is a "text/plain", its going to give you the text version of the file's binary, which looks like what you are seeing.

Comment: I am even able to open that in firefox